Does ceiling effect of outcome variable violate linearity assumption of linear regression
If there is a ceiling effect in the outcome variable, e.g. in my case the outcome variable is limited to a certain value and 25% of data points have that highest possible value, does this mean that linearity (or normality of residuals) is violated, or not necessarily?
If it does violate the assumption, could I mitigate the issue by log transforming the outcome variable?

Even if you take a logarithm, won’t there be a ceiling to the logged values?

@Dave I was confused about that actually, because I often see people log transform variables that are skewed, in order to change the distribution, but in my case it did nothing (created more of a ceiling effect, if anything)

What is the nature of the ceiling effect.  Is this the true maximum the output can ever take?

@Demetri Pananos The variable is a clinical score of severity, so the max value is the highest value it can have, but there is an underlying latent variable (actual severity) which the score is modeling

Those values at the ceiling represent a lower limit to the true outcome values. The technical term for that is right censoring. Linearity of response and normality of errors around predictions from a simple linear model is thus going to be violated (unless those ceiling values are the same as the true values).
There are several ways to proceed nevertheless, generally related to survival analysis, in which many individuals have not yet died (or experienced some other event of interest) at the end of the study period. The time-to-event value for those individuals in survival analysis is similarly at some upper limit.
If the ceiling represents something like an upper limit to some instrument response, you could consider a tobit model that take the true value to be a "latent variable," linearly related to the predictor variables as in a linear regression, that ends up at the ceiling if it is greater than that. Coefficient estimates are those that maximize the likelihood of the data under those assumptions.
Other approaches, under the general heading of ordinal regression, require fewer assumptions. Examples are the Cox proportional hazard models and proportional odds models. Frank Harrell discusses them on this web page. Implementations are available in standard statistical software packages.

Ceiling effects can affect the linearity of an outcome, but this will depend on the degree of maximum values present in the data. Sometimes very minor ceiling effects will have very little effect on the linearity of the distribution of values (e.g. less than 1% of the sample reaches the max value of the response), though there will still be potential issues with predictions out-of-sample regardless.
As a basic example, here is some data I simulated in R. It basically approximates two count variables, one uniformly distributed predictor and one binomially distributed response, so that they both range from 0 to 100 possible values. The response in this situation has many ceiling values.
#### Simulate Data ####
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
x <- runif(n,0,100)
b0 <- 0
b1 <- .2
z <- b0 + b1*x
p <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(n,100,p)

#### Plot ####
plot(
  x,y,
  pch=21,
  bg="gray",
  col="gray",
  main="Simulated Ceiling Data"
  )

And sure enough, our data doesn't look linear.

As to whether or not logging the values helps, this doesn't fix matters at all, and only serves to put the data on a new scale which has a much lower range of values.
plot(
  x,log(y),
  pch=21,
  bg="gray",
  col="gray",
  main="Logged Simulated Ceiling Data"
)


The nature of the data will dictate how it should be modeled if it is bounded in some way. Count responses tend to use Poisson, negative binomial, or other discrete response regressions. Proportions can be modeled with beta regressions (when continuous), logistic regression (when made up of discrete trials), or other methods (e.g. the Dirichlet regression for more than 2 categories).
